# SQL Job using proxy for psexec task not working - no errors

Tags: sql-server, ssis, proxy, jobs, psexec

I've had the same issue for a long time where a SQL job run from a domain user proxy is running a psexec task (connecting to another server and running an exe on that server). There are no errors, it shows as complete, but doesn't seem to run anything on the remote server. I've tried SSIS and CMD exec steps. However, it works if the proxy credential user is logged in on the SQL server.

It works fine through SQL Data Tools in Debug.

It works using a batch file or a windows scheduled task using the same user as in the SQL proxy credential, even if that user is logged off.

The user has the run as batch job privileges on both servers.

Does anyone have any suggestions, or is there a windows log event that I could check in relation to the proxy account?